# "Whoever able"?

Tags: verbs, pronouns

A friend of mine wrote

> Whoever able to understand these few words [...] may draw my attention.

First, I told him to write "*Anyone who is able* to understand [...]", but he said he wants to keep the word "Whoever". Ok. With that assumption, for me, it would sound better if he said "Whoever *being* able to understand these few words [...] may draw my attention."

My question: Would you say that his sentence is correct without adding any word between "Whoever" and "able"?

Comment: Your friend is definitely wrong. *Anyone able* would be correct.

Answer (score 7):

The word that should go between "Whoever" and "able" is **is**.

**Note:** "being" could be used correctly if the sentence reads like "Whoever, being able to understand x, does y may draw my attention", although I doubt you would likely hear this in speech.

Comment: Right. That sounds good to me. Would you say that "being" would be incorrect? Thanks.

Comment: If the sentence is as straightforward as it looks, then yes. However, "being" could be used correctly if the sentence reads like "Whoever, being able to understand x, does y may draw my attention".

Answer (score 4):

Nobody has directly addressed the question of why "whoever able to ... " is ungrammatical, whereas "anyone able to ... " works.

The point is that "who(ever)" is a relative pronoun, and must introduce a full clause with a finite verb. "Anyone" is not a relative pronoun, and so cannot introduce such a clause.

"Who", "whoever" and "whosoever" all have the same grammar.

So

> whoever is able to
>
> anyone who is able to
>
> anyone able to

are all grammatical

but

> *whoever able to ... may ...
>
> *anyone is able to  ... may ...

are not.

Incidentally, "draw my attention" reads oddly without an object: to me it *requires* a "to ... " phrase.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question? *No.* A suitable modification which would satisfy your friend's request, yet isn't as verbose as *is able to,* is:

> Whoever can understand these few words...

Comment: +1 because if OP's friend insists on retaining *whoever*, that's the best you can do. But I'm guessing neither OP nor his friend are "careful" native speakers, because really it should be *Whosoever can understand...*

Comment: No, I'm not an English native speaker. I'm a Spanish native speaker, and so is my friend. Thank you.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: no, "whosoever" is a rather old-fashioned alternative to "whoever". There's nothing wrong with "whoever". Or by "careful" do you mean "preciously archaic"?

Comment: @Colin: On reflection I think you're right. I was drawn into an archaic mode because OP's entire sentence and sentiment reminded me of the biblical [He that hath an ear, let him hear what the Spirit saith...](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Revelation+2%3A17&version=KJV)

Answer (score 0):

It might (just) be acceptable to say "Whomsoever, able to understand these few words, may draw my attention."   This (obsolescent) use of *whomsoever* is equivalent to *anyone*, and does not vary to *whosoever*.  But it's somewhat precious at best, and may depend on what is in the omitted words.

Comment: +1 for "precious", which all valid variants would be.

Comment: -1 for not knowing the difference between "who(soever)" and "whom(soever)". Normally I wouldn't make a fuss about this nearly obsolete distinction, but if somebody is going to be precious enough to use "who(m)soever" I expect them to get the right one of them.

Comment: @Colin: you've missed my point. It's not the standard "Who(so)ever *is* able to understand": it's more  "He counts it lawfull in the bookes of whomsoever to reject that which hee finds otherwise then true."(Milton, Of Reformation). Granted, I wouldn't have suggested it if I'd known Op wasn't a native speaker...

Comment: Apparently I did miss your point. OK, you did not make the error I accused you of, but I'm quite unable to find a way of making the sentence you did post grammatical.